# Imitating symbology for DEM / Hillshading in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem, symbology, hillshade

[image: An image of a map from the DFO Pacific Website]

I am using ArcMap 10.2 and I am looking to copy the basemap styling from this map but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

I have a DEM of the area and the hillshading layer used but I'm not sure how to get the DEM to be shaded from green to tan based on the elevation. It's not an option in my symbology for raster dater.

Comment: It looks like an elevation tint with a transparent hillshade, areas outside the focus area are flat grey, the best you can do is find/create a colour ramp to match and adjust the transparency of your hillshade (black to white) until it matches by eye. How you accomplish this is dependent on your software.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I believe you are right as that is what I've experimented with. ~30% contrast and brightness with ~80% transparency. I can't seem to get the DEM to look right though.

Comment: you have to try different cutoff for the DEM to see if you are using the right cutoff that will give you similar categories as the picture

Comment: ArcMap 10.2 will have the colour ramp in the symbology tab of the layer properties.. as long as it's been set to 'stretched' and not one of the other renderer types. You might also need to adjust the stretch from the default to min-max and manually enter the min/max values to get it to look right. That is assuming your data is Raster data on your local and not a basemap; basemaps (can) have their renderer predetermined and unmodifiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/styles-and-symbols/working-with-color-ramps.htm

Using the above link and the colour picker in Photoshop to obtain the high and low colour RGB values, I was able to achieve the style of DEM that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

The eye dropper tool works wonders if you don't know what the color is but want to figure it out.

http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcwatch/1214/finding-colors-on-maps-is-easy-using-the-eye-dropper-tool

The trick in your case is that there is an underlying hillshade that is interacting with the colors.  I'd pick a low elevation and a high elevation with relatively moderate hillshade values.  Use the eye dropper tool to get the RGB values.  In ArcGIS you can set the two end colors in a color ramp by right clicking on the color ramp of the layer in the Table of Contents (left panel where all of the layers are listed).  If your attached map isn't a georeferenced layer you can still bring it into ArcGIS as an image and use the eye dropper, but you'll need to manually guess which areas have high and low hillshade values.

Alternatively, just e-mail the authors if you can find their names and ask.